# Truffle Suit, real network simulation?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, truffle, ganache

I'm working on a Dapp for testing Ethereum smart contracts.

I have followed along with this tutorial: https://github.com/Quintor/angular-truffle-box and got the Truffle Dapp working with Ganache-CLI, making me able to do Crypto (I.e. Ethereum) transactions from one to another wallet on this blockchain. 
*Note, this is a testing environment so no real Eth are transferred.

The problem I currently encounter is that transactions are direct, and not like the times that are displayed as an option. (Like here, https://ibb.co/ccR8k0J)

The idea is that the more Ethereum (Cryptocurrency) you pay as a fee, the faster the transaction will be done. I wonder if anyone knows how to simulate these times, but on a local blockchain instead of a deployed one.

Comment: ganache doesn't have options to set the consensus mechanism. You could look at puppeth to quickly spin up a geth instance with whatever consensus you want.

Comment: @StephenS Do you have any experience with Eth +  Puppeth or simulating a Consensus mechanism? I tried it but I can't seem to fully get it to work.
( am also open to other communication platforms, if that may suit you more)

Comment: The timings you see in Metamask are for a real network possibly using PoW. Mining with PoW is resource intensive and simulating the timings might require setting up multiple nodes so that transactions with higher gas prices will be finished faster. My current setup is not so powerful, I might try this on a different machine and check...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ganache doesn't have options to set the consensus mechanism. You could look at puppeth to quickly spin up a geth instance with whatever consensus you want."

By @Stephen S